# `docker logs` vs `docker container logs`

Tags: docker

There seems to be two commands to fetch logs from a container

`docker logs <container_name>`

eg

`tapan@y500:~$ docker logs es
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was 
deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future 
release.
[2018-11-02T16:35:26,485][INFO ][o.e.n.Node] [] 
initializing...`

or

`docker conainer logs <container_name>`

`tapan@y500:~$ docker container logs es
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
[2018-11-02T16:35:26,485][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...`

What is the difference between them if any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this pull request https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/26025

Docker CLI evolved and they kept old commands.

So basically `docker container logs` refers to the same code than `docker logs`.